# send latitude & longitude on Server at 15 minute time interval

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location

I want to send lat and long of device on server with 15 minute time interval even my app is not running in background. Is that Possible or Not.

Comment: Background it is possible, but if you kill app then doesn't, appstore would not allow such app. another thing it will drain device battery as well.

Comment: this thing is possible in android with help of handler's so why not in iOS.

Comment: Not possible on ios. In android, you can create background service which can be executed even when your app is terminated. But in iOS, If your app is terminated, nothings get executed-except push notification/local notification- which obviously not helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

Background it is possible, but if you kill app then doesn't, Appstore would not allow such app. another thing it will drain device battery as well.

Enable background modes.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, this will only deliver updates when the location changes, not based on time, so if the user is stationary for 30 minutes, for example, there won't be any update

Comment: yes @Paul ,it just enable location updates but i need to run any background thread or service which can run even app is not running.

Comment: this thing is possible in android with help of handler's so why not in iOS

Comment: @SumitDhariwal - Alternatively you can use PushKit, but your app must have feature of VOIP. there is no such thread or service which will get location in app's kill state and send it to server via API. Ideally not possible.

Comment: Android app can run separate service, which keeps running even main app is being killed.

Comment: Background location updates will happen if your app is suspended or killed due to memory pressure, but not if the user explicitly kills the app.  A significant difference between iOS and Android is that iOS favours the user, not the developer.  If the user kills an app then iOS assumes they wanted it dead